# youtube API V3 Search Python

Tags: python, youtube-api, flask

I am Trying to use the [youtube-api V3 search](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search). I have a flask web application and am trying to output the results into rows on the webpage.

I started with the [Google developers pages](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python#search_by_keyword) (works perfect in terminal) then found [this great sounding example](https://github.com/youtube/yt-samples-python-app-engine-search-by-keyword/blob/master/main.py) which would output thumbnails and hyper links from the results. However it ran on Google app engine and I am trying to create a Flask application.

So with my very limited knowledge I have tried to merge them to fit my needs.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.tools import argparser
import sys
import os
import urllib

# Set API_KEY to the "API key" value from the "Access" tab of the
# Google APIs Console http://code.google.com/apis/console#access
# Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API and Freebase API
# for your project.
API_KEY = "REPLACE ME" #Yes I did replace this with my API KEY
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"
QUERY_TERM = "dog"

def search_by_keyword():
    youtube = build(
      YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, 
      YOUTUBE_API_VERSION, 
      developerKey=API_KEY
    )
    search_response = youtube.search().list(
      q=QUERY_TERM,
      part="id,snippet",
      maxResults=25
    ).execute()

    videos = []

    for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
    if search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
            videos.append("%s (%s)" % (search_result["snippet"]["title"],
                                       search_result["id"]["videoId"]))

print "Videos:\n", "\n".join(videos), "\n"

if __name__ == "__main__":
  try:
    youtube_search()
  except HttpError, e:
    print "An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status, e.content)
```

What I actually want it to do is return results to my webpage rather than just print but thought it was best to take one step at a time. If I can make it work in terminal I could then sort it on a webpage, but not as simple as I thought.

Currently I receive error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "search.py", line 38, in <module>
    print "Videos:\n", "\n".join(videos), "\n"
NameError: name 'videos' is not defined
```

Which is my first main hurdle as I was expecting it to work as it did in both examples I took it from.

My second problem is how do I go about converting results (assuming I could fix above) into a table on the webpage?

I plan to have

```
@app.route('/search')
```

include the above code and then;

```
return render_template ('search.html')
```

But unsure how to pass the results back onto it, do I still need the print for this or is it another term I should be using? I want to be able to use the VideoID returned from each to sort thumbnails and links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your list of videos is a local variable and doesn't exist outside your function "search_by_keyword()" to access the videos variable, you could return that variable like so:

```
def search_by_keyword():
youtube = build(
  YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, 
  YOUTUBE_API_VERSION, 
  developerKey=API_KEY
)
search_response = youtube.search().list(
  q=QUERY_TERM,
  part="id,snippet",
  maxResults=25
).execute()

videos = []

for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
if search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
        videos.append("%s (%s)" % (search_result["snippet"]["title"],
                                   search_result["id"]["videoId"]))
return videos
```

in your main function you could use something like:

```
videos = search_by_keyword()
```

in that way you could print the videos to the console or send it to a template with Flask.

Comment: thank you for your reply. However I am still unsure how I can use this  videos output to create the table I desire. Could you elaborate any more or point me in the right direction?

Comment: with Flask you can send variables to a template:
return render_template('videotable.html', videos = videos)
in your template you could put a {% for video in videos %} block to create a table out of the videos

Comment: so simple and yet i've spent days on it. Many thanks

Comment: Sorry to still be asking questions as surely I should be able to do this. But I get the response onto my page as a long string of text. I am unable to pull out the "title" and "videoId" for manipulation as i wish to use the videoId to generate thumbnails and embeded videos. Thanks in advance